# Process.Start() and Windows permissions on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, process, permissions, assemblies

Here's the situation: I've got an asp.net webpage who calls Process.Start() to do some work. When I do this on my development machine, it simply works. When I try it on a fresh Windows 7 install, I'm having issues running that other process (which is also a .NET application).

That program depends on, among other assemblies, the **OOXML SDK DLL**. When trying it on the deploy machine, I'm getting "Access Denied" exceptions when the program attempts to load the OOXML assembly. When trying to simply run the exe instead of doing it by Process.Start, there are no problems and the application works. I've tried settings permissions for IIS's Application Pool, IUSR account and all the basic solutions for usual Process.Start problems. I'm lost, what am I missing?

Some more information:

1) I can't find any differences between IIS configurations for the deploy/develop machines.
2) I've installed the OOXML SDK on the deploy machine but somehow the process still can't load it

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have tried setting permissions, was it on the OOXML folder? You could try checking if the IIS account has read access to the folder where the OOXML dlls are placed.

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting permissions on the OOXML folder under Program Files, Temporary ASP.NET Files, and the folder where the exe is located. The exe still can't load the assembly.